# Converter numeros em decimal em assembly8086

Tags: assembly, 8086

Pessoal estou tentando desenvolver uma calculadora de somar em assembly8086 só que não estou conseguindo converter os números em somas acima de 10, se somar 4+5 = 9 funciona perfeito agora se eu somar 8+2=10 ele não exibi o resulto 10 em vez exibi apenas dois ponto ":".

```
org 100h
```

.MODEL small

.STACK 512d

.DATA

```
mensagem1 db "Digite o primeiro numero: $"
mensagem2 db " Digite o segunndo numero: $"

mensagem3 db " A Soma e: $"
```

valor1 db ?  ; mensagem
valor2 db ?  ; mensagem

.CODE

```
  lea dx, mensagem1
  mov ah, 09h
  int 21h

    mov ah, 01h
    int 21h

    mov bl, al

    mov valor1, bl

  lea dx, mensagem2
  mov ah, 09h
  int 21h 

    mov ah, 01h
    int 21h
      mov bl, al
    mov valor2, bl

  mov dx, offset mensagem3
  mov ah, 9
  int 21h

  mov dh, valor1
  add dh, valor2

aam             ;
                ; Convertendo para decimal o resultado
sub dh, 30h   ; 



mov dl,dh
mov ah, 02h
int 21h

ret
```

Alguém poder me da um help agradeço.